# Update item number when dropping using jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this working, sort of, but only updates number on second drop, not first. What am I doing wrong here?

Basically trying to update the "span.digit" when reordered using drag/drop. This way the number updates to match the new location in the list. I know I'm close to getting this to work - just not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any explanation would be very helpful. Thanks!

```
$("#sortableQb2").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $('#sortableQb2 > li').each(function (i) {
            var humanNum = i + 1;
            $(this).find("span.digit").html(humanNum + '');
        });
    }
});

<ul id="sortableQb2">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                 <a href="#!" class="btn btn-link"><span class="digit">1</span>Some Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                 <a href="#!" class="btn btn-link"><span class="digit">2</span>Some Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                 <a href="#!" class="btn btn-link"><span class="digit">3</span>Some Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6t095h9/2/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
$( function() {
    $( "#sortableQb2" ).sortable({
        update: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#sortableQb2 > li > ul > li > a > span.digit').each(function (i) {
                var humanNum = i + 1;
                $(this).html(humanNum + '');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6t095h9/3/